# Pandas Delete Row of Data where Index is String

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where a few indexes are string values.  How can I delete the rows of data where the index is a string value or a non integer?  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using boolean indexing:

```
mask = frame.index.map(lambda x: not isinstance(x, str))
frame = frame[mask]
```

Comment: I believe that before I set the index for the dataframe, the data type of that series is a string.  So that when I run the boolean indexing, all of the dataframe is cleared.  I try to change the datatype of the series before setting the index but I get the following error: invalid literal for int() with base 10 .  Any suggestions?

Comment: @scriptdiddy: To avoid the error, replace `int(x)` with the expression `int(text) if x.isdigit() else x`.